# StackWatch - Glitch app to send Web Push Notifications on new questions

Tags: app, questions, website, notifier

I made a very simple node app to give me chrome push notifications when new questions are posted in tags I am interested in:

[image: notification banner]

I have tested it working in Chrome and Firefox.

### [Demo Site](https://stackWatch.glitch.me)

This is a version that is subscribed to a lot of the most frequent tags. You can hit "Subscribe" there to see what notifications look like.

Since it is hosted on [glitch](https://glich.com), it is trivial to "remix the site" to host your own instance that you can customize to whatever tags you want. All you need to do is edit the `.env` file in your "remixed" version:

```
TAGS="go,angularjs,redis,git,sql"
SITE="http://stackoverflow.com"
SITE_ID=1
```

Your instance will listen to websockets for new questions on those tags, and will push notifications to anyone subscribed.

#### Features

- Simple push notifications you can click to take you to the question.
- Doesn't require page to stay open, just browser process.
- Site generates direct link to filtered search so you can get there easily. (Similar to custom tabs on SE sites, but a little easier for me to find)
- Free hosting on glitch. Trivial to remix and customize
- Prometheus metrics at /metrics if you are interested in stats or monitoring
- [Open Source](https://github.com/captncraig/stackWatch)

Comment: The first two links seem to be dead.